# Edit pickle matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dumped a matplotlib figure using pickle. I am able to load it successfully but how to edit this figure such as change the title etc?

Below is the sample code to dump the figure-

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(b=False)
ax.set_title('title', fontsize=22)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=20)
ax.plot(x, y)

import pickle as pkl
pkl.dump(fig,file('sin.pickle','wb'))
```

This is how I load it-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle as pkl

# Load figure from disk and display
fig = pkl.load(open('sin.pickle','rb'))
plt.show()
```

I want to edit the following

- Remove the title
- Enable the grid
- Set the labels for x and y axis

Comment: I think you should be able to recover `ax` with `fig.axes[0]`.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked!

Answer (score 1):

To set the label for x and y axis:

```
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=16)
```

To enable grid, call:

```
plt.grid(True)
```

Before calling:

```
plt.show()
```